# My .py file closes immediately after running without giving output

Tags: python

When I run a .py file, it just opens and closes immediately. It doesn't give any output. I turned it into an .exe file but still the same result. I ran it from cmd, the result is the same. I checked the program that runs the code and found it to be Python.

HERE IS THE CODE.

from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

app.geometry("250x250")

app.title("Tkinter!")

mainloop()

Comment: You need to share the code and explain what happen when you do (from command line): `python my_script.py`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to kindly share the code(as there may be some codes that does not have an output. For example, if the code simply involves assigning values to a variable(say x=2+4) will not result in printing an output, unless specifically mentioned otherwise(print(x)). Also, ensure that you add the Python's installed location to PATH(Environment Variables). I am assuming that you are using Windows OS(as you mentioned cmd).

Comment: from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

app.geometry("250x250")

app.title("Tkinter!")

mainloop()